# Make an random value from array where most selected value will one

Tags: php

How to get random value from array set an value in array that will  be one to selected more than other?

```
array('00','01','02');
```

I want to select an random value from this array with most selected value be '00', i.e the '00' value will be selected 80% and other two values will be 20%.

Here array can have many values, its only an example with three values

Comment: You could use mt_rand to produce a random number between say 0 and 100, then if ($random < 80) {$yourarray[0], or something - maybe a switch statement.  That'd probably work.  I won't bother posting as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$main_array=array('00','01','02');

$priority=array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2);

$rand_index=array_rand($priority);//select a random index from priority array.. $priority[$rand_index] will give you index 0 or 1 or 2 with your priority set..

echo $main_array[$priority[$rand_index]];
```

I think the code is self explanatory...

***Array will have many elements*** case will come when lets say the requirement will come like 3% probability of "00" 28% prob. of "01" rest to other elements...In that case use array_fill function to fill elements in masses...and array_merge them

Like for the same case I've taken answer will be

```
$main_array=array('00','01','02');
$priority1=array_fill(0,69,2);
$priority2=array_fill(0,28,1);
$priority3=array_fill(0,3,0);    
$priority=array_merge($priority1,$priority2,$priority3);

$rand_index=array_rand($priority);

echo $main_array[$priority[$rand_index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a parallel array with the probability distribution, e.g.:

```
array('80', '10', '10');
```

Use standard random number function to generate a number between 0 and 99, then look it up in this array. The index you find it at is then used as the index to the values array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea.

```
$arr = array('00', '01', '02');
$randInt = rand(1, 10);

if ($randInt <= 8) {
    $value = $arr[0];
}
else if ($randInt == 9) {
    $value = $arr[1];
}
else { // ($randInt == 10)
    $value = $arr[2];
}
```

There is now an 80% chance that `$value` contains '00', a 10% chance that it contains '01', and a 10% chance it contains '02'.  This may not be the most efficient solution, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

one of many options

```
$a = array_fill(0, 8, '0');
$a['9']='1';
$a['10']='2';

echo $a[array_rand($a,1)];
```